# How to remove CH3 labels from a molecule's image? [OpenBabel in Python]

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-structure

I would like to remove CH3 labels from svg images generated in openbabel in Python.
I am thinking I should use `obConversion.SetOptions("w",openbabel.OBConversion.OUTOPTIONS)` and replace "w" with another character. This does not work. Do you have any ideas? The image is below, for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obConversion.AddOption("C",openbabel.OBConversion.OUTOPTIONS)
```

Referenced openbabel [documentation](http://openbabel.org/docs/dev/FileFormats/SVG_depiction.html). Setting it to "C" will remove terminal carbons.